# How can I reword "cross-gender" so it doesn't sound like I'm talking about transgenders?

Tags: word-choice, gender-neutral

> This research has been focused on cross-national and cross-gender applications of such theories.

The use of "cross-gender" means across genders, in the same way that "cross-national" means across nations. However, my concern is that readers will think I mean "transgender." How can I revise this sentence to avoid such confusion?

Comment: If *cross-national* could mean *trans-national*, there's always that risk. The entire sentence would better be rephrased more clearly as *across nationalities and genders* or some better way. (You could probably be meaning geographies, not nationalities, I'm not sure.)

Comment: Yes, geographies, not nationalities.

Comment: Perhaps the intended meaning is more clear in context, but here it looks like “cross-national” means nation-to-nation and  “cross-gender” unavoidably means male-to-female or female-to-male applications, albeit not in a transgendering sense.  Anyway, the sentence is pompous research-paper jargon; rewrite it without using any of the terms *focus, cross, national, gender, application*.

Comment: @jwpat7 It *is* a research paper -- how can it not have research-paper jargon, pompous or otherwise? Lol.

Answer (score 7):

> This research has been focused on applications of such theories across geographies and genders.

is what I would suggest from the top of my head.

Answer (score 2):

The *pan-* prefix does not have the same connotation, so try *pan-gender applications*.

*Online Etymology Dictionary*:

> **pan-**
>   prefix meaning "all, every, whole, all-inclusive," from Gk. *pan*-, combining form of *pas* (neut. *pan*, masculine and neuter genitive *pantos*) "all," from PIE **pant*- "all" (with derivatives found only in Greek and Tocharian). Commonly used as a prefix in Greek, in modern times often with nationality names, the first example of which seems to have been *Panslavism* (1846). Also *panislamic* (1881), *pan-American* (1889), *pan-German* (1892), *pan-African* (1900), *pan-European* (1901), *pan-Arabism* (1930).

Comment: However, *pan-* necessarily implies *all*, not *across some*.

Comment: @Kris True, but where do you get "across *some*"? OP did not write it.

Answer (score 2):

You can consider using [gender-neutral](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gender-neutral):

> - Applicable or available to either gender (to both males and females).
>
>   *The women's sleeping quarters are on the left side of the dormitory, the men's are on the right; **gender-neutral** restrooms are located in the middle.*
>
>   *Many modern laws use **gender-neutral** constructions like "he or she" in place of the old, supposedly unmarked "he".*
> - Not indicating or restricted by gender, and thus applicable or *available to those of any gender and to those of no gender*.
>
>   *Gender-neutral pronouns like "ey" and "ze" are used by many genderqueer, intersex and neutrois individuals.*

Comment: How would we fit that into the sentence in question? :(

Comment: Either you misunderstood the question or I phrased it poorly. I do not mean "gender neutral." I am referring to research that makes comparisons across genders, in the same way that some research might study comparisons across nations. In the same way that I do not mean "nation neutral," I do not mean "gender neutral."

Comment: @Bob Then I would suggest rephrasing your sentence as Kris and Bill have suggested. There is no word, afaik, that accurately suggests a comparison **between** the two primary genders without potentially implying the neutral. Apparently, [intergender](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/intergender) does exist.

Answer (score 1):

[Unisex](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/unisex) *(undifferentiated as to sex)* would often be suitable, but perhaps not in OP's context. Partly because it would imply a single [application of such theories] applicable to both male and female, and partly because it wouldn't sit well next to *cross-national*.

I suggest rewording to something like...

> This research has been focused on applications of such theories that transcend the boundaries of nationality and gender.

EDIT: Apparently OP's context is ***concerned with*** differences across those boundaries, rather than "neutral/unaffected by" those boundaries. In which case *focus on/exploit/whatever* could be used instead of *transcend*. Wiothout knowing exactly *why* the differences are significant, I can't say which word would be best.

Comment: Nope, that is not what I mean. The way that "cross-national" is used is to mean "comparisons across nations." I need something similar for gender. Saying "transcends the boundaries of nationality" is not what I mean, both because I mean geographies and not citizenship, but also because it loses the "comparisons across" meaning.

Comment: @Bob: In that case, just change *transcend* to *explore, focus on* or similar. I did say you want "something like" my suggestion. But I must say if ***comparisons across*** those boundaries is where the focus lies, I doubt your original would normally be thus interpreted anyway. You'd have wanted the prefix *inter-* rather than *cross-*, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just say ***across genders*** instead of risking being misunderstood by using an ambiguous term?

The other alternative is to use ***cross-gender*** and then add an explanatory parenthetical remark, e.g., "**(*across genders*, not *transgender*)**. That way you can use your preferred term because you've stipulated what it means on first use.